# JavaScript: Element style.display = 'block' is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom, html-table

I have a table.

1. Within my table, the cells have a comment icon.
2. When clicking on the icon, it should disappear and you should be able to see a textarea, with a button to exit it.
3. If you click on that  button, the comment icon should show again.

I think the CSS is overriding the JavaScript, because the console is telling me I have the correct element to change the display property on. Here's the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript I'm working with:

```js
function hideComment(){
  this.parentNode.style.display="none";
  this.parent.firstChild.style.display="block";
}

var exitButton = document.querySelectorAll(".exit-button");
for (var i = 0; i < exitButton.length; i++){
exitButton[i].addEventListener ('click', hideComment, false);
}

function addComment(){
  this.style.display = 'none';
  this.nextSibling.style.display = "block";
}

var displayComment = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-comment-o");
for (var i = 0; i < displayComment.length; i++){
  displayComment[i].addEventListener('click', addComment, false);
}
```

```css
.c-na-table textarea,
.c-na-table button{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<p>This table enables users to leave a comment in one of the cells.</p>

<div class="table-three">
<table class="c-na-table">
  <thead class="th-head">
    <tr>
      <td class="td-input"></td>
      <td class="column-a-0c no-lite">Course 1</td>
      <td class="column-b-0c no-lite">Course 2</td>
      <td class="column-c-0c no-lite">Course 3</td>
      <td class-"column-d">Comments &nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row-a">
      <td class="td-input"><input type="checkbox"></input></td>
      <td class="column-a-3">Specification 1</td>
      <td class="column-b-3">Specification 1</td>
      <td class="column-c-3">Specification 1</td>
      <td class="column-d"><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><div id="ta-one">
  <button class="exit-button">&#215;</button> 
<textarea row="4" col="20"></textarea>
</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-b">
      <td class="td-input"><input type="checkbox"></input></td>
      <td class="column-a-3">Specification 2</td>
      <td class="column-b-3">Specification 2</td>
      <td class="column-c-3">Specification 2</td>
      <td class="column-d"><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><div id="ta-two">
  <button class="exit-button">&#215;</button> 
<textarea row="4" col="20"></textarea>
</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row-c">
      <td class="td-input"><input type="checkbox"></input></td>
      <td class="column-a-3">Specification 3</td>
      <td class="column-b-3">Specification 3</td>
      <td class="column-c-3">Specification 3</td>
      <td class="column-d"><i class="fa fa-comment-o" aria-hidden="true"></i><div id="ta-three">
  <button class="exit-button">&#215;</button>
  <textarea row="4"col="20"></textarea>
</div></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot class="tf-foot">
    <tr></tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: It might be easier/better to use the `.hide` class rather than adding your `display: none` rule to those selectors, then have your code add or remove the `hide` class (`this.classList.add('hide')`, `this.classList.remove('hide');`, etc.)

Comment: Use `.parentNode` or  `.parentElement`. In pain JS, `parent` is used to reference the parent page from a child page in an iframe

Comment: ok so the button's parent is gone which makes the button (ie. this) gone by default.`this.parent.firstChild.style.display="block"` So this is the same parent but anything within the parent is still going to be `none`. That is if you actually got `parent` to work....

Comment: As zer00ne says, once you set the parent to none, it and all it's descendants are out of the flow. It doesn't matter what you set them to, they will not be visible.

Comment: Good idea, @RobM. It's always nice to see alternative solutions.

Comment: @zer00ne yes, that worked.

Comment: @RobG that makes sense, thank you.

Comment: @HannahBanana— *how* you set the style is not really relevant in this case, it's *what* you set it too and the document structure that matters. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, the CSS was overriding the JavaScript. Would like to know why.

Solved.

```
var textAreaDiv1 = document.getElementById('ta-one').style.display='none';
var textAreaDiv1 = document.getElementById('ta-two').style.display='none';
var textAreaDiv1 = document.getElementById('ta-three').style.display='none';

function hideComment(){
  this.parentNode.style.display="none";
  this.parentNode.parentNode.firstChild.style.display="block";
}

var exitButton = document.querySelectorAll(".exit-button");
for (var i = 0; i < exitButton.length; i++){
exitButton[i].addEventListener ('click', hideComment, false);
}

function addComment(){
  this.style.display = 'none';
  this.nextSibling.style.display = "block";
}

var displayComment = document.querySelectorAll(".fa-comment-o");
for (var i = 0; i < displayComment.length; i++){
  displayComment[i].addEventListener('click', addComment, false);
}
```

Comment: It was overriding it because of [CSS Specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/_. JS affects the elements with a lower specificity.